# what functions are called when i do vi

Tags: vim, filesystems, fuse

When I do a vi filename from the command prompt, what fuse functions are called if I am using the fusexmp example ? I could guess  mknod, open are called.
When I do a write ie when i do :wq write is called. is that right.

Comment: vi/vim is open source. I suggest you get the source and look through it. What's a fuse function?

Comment: you can see for yourself by using dtrace, systemtap, or even oprofile (with kernel support).  start one of those, then use vi, and then get a report of all the calls!

Comment: fusexmp example that comes with the download has some functions defined. I meant to refer to those functions

Answer (score 3):

There's no *fantastically* easy way to see which FUSE functions are called for any given file operation, but running `strace(1)` will record the *system calls*, which is quite close to the FUSE functions:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/vim.all vim /etc/motd
```

A lot of those system calls aren't related to the one file specifically, but to the process of loading `vim`, its dynamically linked libraries, your local configuration, and all its supporting files.

Here's some selected lines that refer to the `/etc/motd` that I opened:

```
stat("/etc/motd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/motd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/motd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/motd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/motd", W_OK)               = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/etc/motd", O_RDONLY)             = 7
close(7)                                = 0
open("/etc/motd", O_RDONLY)             = 7
read(7, "Welcome to Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Lin"..., 8192) = 183
read(7, "", 65536)                      = 0
close(7)                                = 0
stat("/etc/motd", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=183, ...}) = 0
```

The intervening lines make the repeated `stat(2)` calls a little less silly looking.